# CSS Change color on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to override my first "color change" with a second.
I'd like to have a silver color on my icon, when hover the text, and red color icon when hovering the icon.

I tried:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li class="liDoc"><a href="">My link</a> <i class="fa fa-trash delDoc">icon</i></li>
```

**CSS**

```
.delDoc {
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.liDoc:hover > .delDoc {
  color: silver;
}

.delDoc:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

Also i tried:

**HTML**

```
<li class="liDoc"><a href="" class="docLink">'+value+'</a> <i class="fa fa-trash delDoc"></i></li>
```

**CSS**

```
.delDoc{
    color: transparent;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.docLink:hover > .delDoc {
    color: silver;
}
.delDoc:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

**FIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/zt393xjm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use and avoid using `!important` in this case, because you can solve it with Specifity:

> Specificity is a weight that is applied to a given CSS declaration, determined by the number of each selector type in the matching selector. When specificity is equal to any of the multiple declarations, the last declaration found in the CSS is applied to the element. Specificity only applies when the same element is targeted by multiple declarations. As per CSS rules, directly targeted element will always take precedence over rules which an element inherits from its ancestor.
>
> **source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

---

In your case the `.delDoc:hover` is less specific as the `.liDoc:hover > .delDoc`. So simply replace the `.delDoc:hover` with `.liDoc > .delDoc:hover` or `.liDoc:hover > .delDoc:hover`.

Please do not use `!important`! The use of `!important` should be discouraged!

---

**The Code (https://jsfiddle.net/zt393xjm/4/):**

```css
.delDoc {
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.liDoc:hover > .delDoc {
  color: silver;
}
.liDoc > .delDoc:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
  <li class="liDoc"><a href="">My link</a>  <i class="fa fa-trash delDoc">icon</i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. The problem is that the first selector is more specific than the second and therefore it takes precedence. You can easily fix that without any `!important` keywords by simply specializing the second selector:

```css
    .delDoc {
      color: transparent;
      font-size: 12px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .liDoc:hover > .delDoc {
      color: silver;
    }
    
    .liDoc > .delDoc:hover {
      color: red;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
  <li class="liDoc"><a href="">My link</a> <i class="fa fa-trash delDoc">icon</i></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So, what will be the best aproach, and why? (instead of important)

Comment: Specifying more specific selectors is more stable than `!important` because they're still overridable by more specific rules. This is the core idea behind cascading style sheets. When using `!important` you can only override those rules by using more specific rules with another `!important` keyword. This creates a second layer of cascading and is hard to debug and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
 https://jsfiddle.net/16Lr39mh/

Here I use  `.liDoc .delDoc:hover`  to make color change on hover.

Comment: Use of `!important` is highly discouraged unless very necessary. Its bad practice as well.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote you, but the use of `important` should be discouraged.

Comment: It is really bad practice to use !important so freely.

Comment: Yes it is reccommended , not to use important.@MuhammadUsman Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, your first selector is more specific:

So this selector: `.liDoc:hover > .delDoc` is more specific than
`.delDoc:hover`.

When you inspect the element, you'll see the `.delDoc:hover` style, with `color: red` get applied, but gets overridden by the `.liDoc:hover > .delDoc` due to specificity.

The easiest solution is to use an `!important`:

`.delDoc:hover {
    color: red !important;
}`

But using an important is concidered as a bad practise.

Another solution is to make the second selector more specific than the first:

```
.liDoc:hover > .delDoc:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

A little cleanup could lead to this: https://jsfiddle.net/zt393xjm/2/

Comment: Thank you. I thought putting the "red code" below the "silver code" will override it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to style the link itself not the element around it.
Add a class to the a element.

```
 <ul>
  <li class="liDoc"><a class="button" href="">My link</a> <i class="fa fa-trash delDoc">icon</i></li>
</ul>
```

Then you can do the following

```
a.button:link{
  color:red;
}

a.button:hover{
  color:yellow;
}
```